# Using count in mongodb while iterating nested lists

Tags: mongodb

*First, an example of 2 possible documents in my database*

```
{

  "_id" : "0"

  "data": { 
             "lettersCollection" : [
               {"lettersList" : ["A","B","C"] },
               {"lettersList" : ["D","T","E"] },
               {"lettersList" : ["X","Y","Z"] },
             ]
          }
}



{

  "_id" : "1"

  "data": { 
            "lettersCollection" : [
              {"lettersList" : ["A","B","D"] },
              {"lettersList" : ["X","Y","Z"] },
              {"lettersList" : ["E","C","M"] },
            ]
          }
}
```

*What am I trying to accomplish?*

I want to make a descending  list of the letters and their number of appearances.

for example: if the database contains only the 2 above documents, the result would be:

```
A - 2
B - 2
C - 2
D - 2
E - 2
X - 2
Y - 2
Z - 2
T - 1
M - 1
```

Note: A letter can appear only once in a document. For example, it is not possible that the letter "B" would appear more than once in any lettersList in a specific document

*What have I tried so far?*

I am quite new to MongoDB, the closer I came to is this query, which works only for a single value (e.g: _id, which is always unique and therefore the count is always 1), and doesn't iterate on nested arrays and doesn't make a descending order:

```
db.test.group({
    "key": {
        "_id": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "countstar": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
        else prev.countstar++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) (which should typically be your first choice for aggregation) to do this:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    // Duplicate the docs, once per lettersCollection element
    {$unwind: '$data.lettersCollection'},
    // Duplicate the docs again, this time once per lettersList
    {$unwind: '$data.lettersCollection.lettersList'},
    // Group them back together by letter and count them
    {$group: {_id: '$data.lettersCollection.lettersList', count: {$sum: 1}}},
    // Sort by count descending
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

Output:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "Z",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "X",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "Y",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "E",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "D",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "C",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "B",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "A",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "M",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "T",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: To be **exactly** what the OP asked then the last pipeline stage would be `{ "sort": { "_id": 1, "count": -1 } }`. But the response here makes much more logical sense. People should take note of that.